# Unable to access website using Tor with scrapy (Resposne status code 400)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, tor

I am trying to use tor with scrapy. To convert socks5 into http I am using [python-proxy](https://github.com/qwj/python-proxy)(pproxy) module. For configuration of tor with help of pproxy I used the command `pproxy -l http://:8080 -r socks5://127.0.0.1:9050`. For quickly checking whether this setup was working or not I used `requests` module. The code is:

```
import requests

url = 'http://icanhazip.com'

proxies = {
    "http": 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', 
    "https": 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
}

response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
response2 = requests.get(url)

print('Tor IP address: ', response.text)
print('My IP address: ', response2.text)
```

The output was:

```
Tor IP address:  18.27.197.252

My IP address:  119.152.110.234
```

which confirmed that pproxy and tor were working properly. The problem happened when I tried use this setup within scrapy. Code for that purpose is as follows:

```
import scrapy


class Test2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test2'
 
    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'http://icanhazip.com'

        # For getting Tor IP
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse,
        meta={'proxy':'http://127.0.0.1:8080'}) 
                     
        # For getting my actual IP
        #yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse) 

    def parse(self, response):
        yield{
            'ip':response.xpath('//p/text()').get()
        }
```

I can't access the site and got http response code 400 error

```
2020-07-01 17:35:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-07-01 17:35:33 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-07-01 17:35:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-07-01 17:35:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET http://icanhazip.com> (referer: None)
2020-07-01 17:35:34 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 http://icanhazip.com>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2020-07-01 17:35:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

I also tried after changing user-agent but had no luck. And I know that this can't be because of user-agent because when I tried it without proxy I was successfully able to get my own IP

```
2020-07-01 17:41:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-07-01 17:41:39 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-07-01 17:41:39 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-07-01 17:41:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://icanhazip.com> (referer: None)
2020-07-01 17:41:40 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://icanhazip.com>
{'ip': '119.152.110.234'}
2020-07-01 17:41:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

I can't understand two things

1. If I am allowed to access the site with my original IP, why I can't access it using tor IP address
2. Let suppose if there is some problem with configuring tor through pproxy, how I am able to access site with Tor IP address using `requests`

**Edit:**

I have observed that it varies from site to site. I am able to access a good amount of sites but not all. Some sites gave http response code 400 error while some other sites gave 403 error. But I was able to access all the sites using my own IP or using `requests` that originally denied access when using TOR IP. I can't figure out what's happening

Comment: What happens if you use http://httpbin.org/ip instead?

Comment: I don't know why but httpbin.org/ip is working fine

Comment: So does this means it varies from website to website?

Comment: Have you checked the body of the 400 response? It may hint at the problem.

Comment: `b'<html>\r\n<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'`